# Swift - Firebase Authentication State Persistence

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently thinking about implementing Firebase Auth to my Swift project, hence I've been reading some articles. - Namely among others [this one.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

**I need some help understanding the given article.** It's about "Authentication State Persistence". Does this mean, that if the value is set to `local`, the user will stay logged in even after closing the app? In other words, will he be able to sign up once and stay logged in until he decides to log out - even when he's offline?

Let's say a user decides not to create an account and logs in with "Anonymous Authentication" (I assume this is the type of login in this kind of case) - will he stay logged in forever as well or is there a danger of data loss, in case of going offline or closing the app?

Answer (score 1):

**First:** the link you provided refers to a javascript firebase documentation

**Second:** the only thing available in IOS is you can create an anonymous user with

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error) in
  // ...
     let user = authResult.user
     let isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous  // true
     let uid = user.uid
}
```

and you can convert it to a permanent user check  [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth)

**Finally:** whether the user is usual / anonymous , after you sign in you need to check this to show login/home screen every app open

```
if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
   print("user exists")
}
else {
   print("No user")
}
```

and the user still exists unless you sign out regardless of whether you closed the app or not

If you are using the latest Firebase version, `FIRAuth` is now `Auth`:

```
if Auth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
   print("user exists")
}
else {
   print("No user")
}
```